# How to call ant script from ant script

Tags: ant

I'm calling an ant script from an ant script. The calling script contains:

```
<ant antfile="calledant.xml" >
  <property name="par1" value="mypar"/>
</ant>
```

I can't figure out how to obtain the passed value in the script that is called. 
I would expect the following to work but it doesn't:

```
<echo message="in calledscript, value is ${par1}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  When I updated my PATH so that a JDK was found before a JRE, an error message went away and it started working.